# Attempting to replace ruby if statement with ternary, code breaks

Tags: ruby, if-statement, ternary-operator

I have an array user_list that contains users. Each user is a hash and has a symbol key :name.

I am working with a spreadsheet, and for a row, the first column aka row[0] contains a name. If I want to update a user's hash with data from the remaining columns of a row, I need to retrieve the correct user hash from user_list.

Here below is code that works:

```
def self.retrieve_user(user_list, row)
    user_list.each do |user|
      if user[:name] == row[0]
        return user
      end
    end
end
```

I was attempting to replace it with this:

```
def self.retrieve_user(user_list, row)
    user_list.each do |user|
      user[:name] == row[0] ? user : nil
    end
end
```

And now my program breaks. What am I missing regarding the ternary operator?

Edit: I am trying to do this because of https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first version of your program, you were iterating through your user list and when you found the user you wanted, you returned the user to whoever called the function (thus immediately breaking out the `each` loop and also the `retrieve_user` function).

In your second version, you aren't explicitly returning any values, nothing is being done to that `user` object you access, it just continues to execute the loop till it gets to the end of the `user_list and then it returns the`user_list` implicitly (this is a Ruby feature). See the following blog post which explains it well: http://www.thedwick.com/2012/08/ruby-implicit-returns-do-as-the-romans-do/

You could replace the code with the following to achieve what you initially wanted in one line

```
def self.retrieve_user(user_list, row)
    user_list.each do |user|
       return user if user[:name] == row[0]
    end
end
```

You should also consider the case where none of the users in the user list match the name of the user (unless you are absolutely sure this can't happen). In the above case, the entire user list will be implicitly returned as the `return user` will not execute since the condition is always false. You could add an explicit return nil at the end if nothing should be returned:

```
def self.retrieve_user(user_list, row)
    user_list.each do |user|
       return user if user[:name] == row[0]
    end
    return nil
end
```

Comment: great thanks, before I even get to the section requiring retrieve user, I parse the spreadsheet to obtain all users (so I can add their hashes to user_list), so i'll go with your first suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using **[Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)**

**From the docs:**

> Passes each entry in enum to block. Returns the first for which block
>   is not false. If no object matches, calls ifnone and returns its
>   result when it is specified, or returns nil otherwise.

**Here is how it looks:**

```
def self.retrieve_user(user_list, row)
  user_list.find{|user| user[:name] == row[0] }
end
```